# Estimate yearly treatment effects for DiD with multiple years pre- and post-treatment in R

Tags: r, difference-in-difference

I've searched quite a while for the answer and still have no clue how I would go about setting up this regression in R.

I have estimated a difference-in-difference treatment effect, simply `y ~ treatment*after`. I have panel data for 5 years pre-treatment and 5 years post-treatment. Now I additionally would like to estimate yearly treatment effects for all pre- and post-treatment years just as [Atkin, Faber and Navarro (2016)](http://www.nber.org/papers/w21176.pdf) did it with monthly data in their paper.  They define their regression as follows: 
[image: desired regression (photo)]

In my data-frame `did`, the treatment happens after 5 years and for simplicity I want to normalize the coefficient on year 5 to zero.  What I tried so far is to create an indicator variable (dummy) for each year 1 to 10, and then create a new data matrix `did2` including these year dummies:

```
dy1  <- as.numeric(did$t==1)
dy1m <- matrix(dy1, ncol=1, nrow=5000)
dy2  <- as.numeric(did$t==2)
...
...

did2 <- cbind(did, dy1m, ... , dy10m)
```

Then, I did the following regression (leaving out fixed effects, clustered errors, etc. for now):

```
lm(y ~ dy1m + ... + dy10m -1, data = did)
```

The resulting coefficients do not make sense at all.  The problem is that I do not even fully understand what this regression model should look like in my case (when we take the model in Atkin, Faber and Navarro (2016) as an example).

How do I program this model?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to fit a regression model with a [factor variable](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/factors.html).  The regression equation in the paper you cite is treating the variable `months-since-entry` as a factor, with possible values between $-13$ up to $36$.  In your coding you appear to be trying to do a regression using a factor variable, by manually creating a set of indicator variables to use in the model.  Fortunately, all this is unnecessary, since `R` has simple functionality to fit regression models with factor variables with a much simpler syntax, without the user having to program the design matrix manually.

To fit your regression, with the variable `t` treated as a factor variable, you can use your original data-frame `did` via the following code:

```
MODEL <- lm(y ~ factor(t), data = did);
```

This code will recognise `t` as a factor variable and will automatically create a design matrix for the regression that consists of indicators for the outcomes of this variable.  There is no need to remove the intercept from the model with this syntax, since `R` will automatically see that the regression should exclude a baseline category for the factor variable from the model.

This should give you a baseline piece of code that allows you to fit a linear regression for your data.  You can then build on this by adding other relevant variables.  It appears from your question that you are a novice in `R` programming, so I would also recommend that you do some study on how to manipulate data frames (e.g., with the `dplyr` package) and how you fit regression models in cases where you have different types of variables.